# intersection of the commutant of a von Neumann algebra and the ultraproduct of the von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

In the proof of Proposition 4.1, I don't understand why $E_M(vv^*)=\lambda$. Is $E_N$ the expectation from $M^{\omega}$ to $M$? Can we deduce that $M'\cap M^{\omega}=\Bbb C1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $E_M$ is the expectation onto $M$. For any $x\in M$,
$$
E_M(vv^*)x=E_M(vv^*x)=E_M(xvv^*)=xE_M(vv^*). 
$$
Hence $E_M(vv^*)\in M\cap M'=\mathbb C$.

---

I cannot make sense of the second equality, as I don't see how $T$ either acts or is an element of $L^2(M)$. It is not used in the rest of the page, though.

For the first equality, since $M$ is dense in $L^2(M)$ we may assume $\xi=z\in M$. Then, thinking of the elements in $M$ as in $M^\omega$,
\begin{align}
\Big\|\sum_j \theta(x_j)zy_j\Big\|_2^2
&=\tau_\omega\big(\sum_{k,j}y_k^*z^*\theta(x_k)\theta(x_j)zy_j\big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1\lambda\,\tau_\omega\big(\sum_{k,j}y_k^*z^*\theta(x_k)\lambda\theta(x_j)zy_j\big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1\lambda\,\tau_\omega\big(\sum_{k,j}y_k^*z^*\theta(x_k)E_M(vv^*)\theta(x_j)zy_j\big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1\lambda\,\tau_\omega\big(E_M\big(\sum_{k,j}y_k^*z^*\theta(x_k)vv^*\theta(x_j)zy_j\big)\big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1\lambda\,\tau_\omega\big(\sum_{k,j}y_k^*z^*\theta(x_k)vv^*\theta(x_j)zy_j\big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1\lambda\Big\|\sum_j v^*\theta(x_j)zy_j\Big\|_2^2
\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1\lambda\Big\|\sum_j x_jv^*zy_j\Big\|_2^2
\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

Comment: May I ask another question : How to derive the two equalities marked in green?

Comment: I added something. What's that text? The number of typos for a single page is significant.

Comment: The proposition is from the paper which I mentioned yesterday.

Comment: $\tau_{\omega}$ is a trace on $M^{\omega}$? But $M^{\omega}$ May not have a trace.

Comment: Yes. But in that case I don't know what $M^\omega$ is, nor what $L^2(M)$ is.

Comment: Let $(M,L^2(M),J, L^2(M)^{+})$ be standard form of a von Neumann Algebra and for any $\varphi\in M_{*}^+$, there exists a unique vector $\xi\in L^2(M)^{+}$ such that $\varphi(x)=\langle  x \xi, \xi\rangle$. If we have the standard form. How to compute the above norm?